# Is there an online archive with letters written by people in the past?

Tags: research

Is there an online (preferably free) archive with letters written by people in the past? (other written material which reflects the era from the point of view of someone who lives in it will also be acceptable)

Comment: http://www.lettersofnote.com/

Comment: Requests for references are considered [off-topic](http://history.stackexchange.com/faq). That said, this question is worth migrating to _meta_.

Comment: In this case, I'd really ask Google first.

Answer (score 2):

There are some letter archives from WWI:

http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rstaley/wwlettr1.htm

http://www.ourecho.com/story-1716-LETTERS-FROM-A-SOLDIER-WWI.shtml

http://soldierswills.nationalarchives.ie/search/sw/index.jsp

http://www.petergknight.com/warletters.html

http://www.canadianletters.ca/collections.php?warid=3

http://www.smythe.id.au/letters/

http://www.bookrix.com/_title-en-l-paige-wwi-letters

As another example, you can read the [letters of Cicero](http://oll.libertyfund.org/index.php?option=com_staticxt&staticfile=show.php?title=541&Itemid=27).